# Stripe card checks coming back null

Tags: stripe-payments

Using the Stripe.js V3 to create a a card element ...

```
var card = elements.create('card', {style: style, hidePostalCode: true});
```

Passing token to my Django backend where I am also building the payment method.

```
payment_method = stripe.PaymentMethod.create(
    type="card",
    card={
        "token": request.POST['stripeToken']
    },
    billing_details= {
        "address": {
            "city": ...,
            "country": 'US',
            "line1": ...,
            "line2": ...,
            "postal_code": ...,
            "state": ...,
        },
        "email": ...,
        "name": ...,
        "phone": ...,
    },
)
```

The response I'm getting from stripe.PaymentMethod.create(...)

```
"checks": {
  "address_line1_check": null,
  "address_postal_code_check": null,
  "cvc_check": "pass"
},
```

Can I validate address_line1_check and address_postal_code_check on PaymentMethod?
If not then what would be the best practice to tell if the card is valid before running payment?

New to stripe sorry if this seems lengthy, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a PaymentMethod doesn't trigger a validation on the card. You'll need to either attach the PaymentMethod to a customer or complete a PaymentIntent to perform those validation checks.